# How to install a package manager on a "apparently" clean Linux distribution

Tags: package-management

I got an hardware that runs Linux, seems to be a quite empty distro. Here is the info that I got about the system:

```
ID="cclinux"
NAME="CCLinux Distribution"
VERSION="2.0 (brant)"
VERSION_ID="2.0"
PRETTY_NAME="CCLinux Distribution 2.0 (brant)"

Linux v700 5.4.47-2.2.0+g5ec03d06f54e #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 4 15:33:04 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
Linux version 5.4.47-2.2.0+g5ec03d06f54e (oe-user@oe-host) (gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 4 15:33:04 UTC 2021
```

For extra infos, here is the [software guide](https://crosscontrol.com/media/qr4e5axc/CC%20Linux%20-%20Software%20Guide_v2.0.0.pdf) and the [programmer's guide](https://crosscontrol.com/media/k3jfn2sv/CC%20Linux%20-%20Programmers%20Guide_v2.0.2.pdf).

The first manual reports that the whole system is running with `systemd` (Chapter 6), which I don't know what actually is. As @Stephen Kitt reports it says

> It is advisable to use the provided package manager to manage these binaries. Refer to the programmer's manual for more information.

but I'm not able to get extra infos from the second manual.

**Question is**: I was used, with all the other distros such as Fedora, Ubuntu, Mint, Slax, exc.., to get packages with a package manager such as dnf or apt. On this version, I don't even find dpkg, so i have no clue on how should i install a package. I actually know that I can get sources form http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ for example I tried to `wget dpkg`, which worked, but then I stuck not knowing how to go on.

```shellsession
root@v700:/usr# sudo yum
sudo: yum: command not found
root@v700:/usr# sudo apt
sudo: apt: command not found
root@v700:/usr# sudo apt-get
sudo: apt-get: command not found
root@v700:/usr# sudo ZYpp
sudo: ZYpp: command not found
root@v700:/usr# sudo dnf
sudo: dnf: command not found
root@v700:/usr# sudo pacman
sudo: pacman: command not found
root@v700:/usr# sudo dpkg
sudo: dpkg: command not found
root@v700:/usr#
```

What should i do in order to install a package manager and use it? Is it even possible?

If you guys can help me just notice that i'm pretty new to Linux, so, kindly, don't assume anything.

Comment: The Software Guide says “It is advisable to use the provided
package manager to manage these binaries. Refer to the programmer’s manual for more information.” (page 20). Have you tried looking at the programmer’s manual?

Comment: https://crosscontrol.com/media/k3jfn2sv/CC%20Linux%20-%20Programmers%20Guide_v2.0.2.pdf

Comment: Here is the programmer guide, i've also read that sentence, but i'm not able to get the point nor to find anything about package management on the other guide.

Comment: ... and [here's](https://crosscontrol.com/media/ve5hjrpq/CC%20Linux%20-%20Programmers%20Guide_v2.0.4.pdf) even newer, 2.0.4. None of the 3 I've checked mention "package manager". Latest one talks about installing Board Support Package and SDK. Support requires registering, you get to talk to a bot which doesn't answer to question "What's package manager of CC Linux" but advises to open a support case. KB search for "package manager" or "programmer's manual" results in "No results" :-D

Comment: These are specialized systems, used in industry, vehicles etc. Correspondingly CC Linux is also a specialized version a'la Kali, not intended for desktop use but running basically a single application for process control, mapping & navigation, display systems... from what I can gather if you want to use this as a regular desktop, you'll need to build basically all applications from source.

Comment: If you're already at a root prompt there's no point whatsoever in using `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCLinux is based on [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/); the basic principle there is that you develop on a full-blown PC, and build system images to install on the target device. That’s why there’s no package manager on the device itself: the contents of the device are static, you’re not supposed to install additional software after the fact.

The [programmer’s guide](https://crosscontrol.com/media/k3jfn2sv/CC%20Linux%20-%20Programmers%20Guide_v2.0.2.pdf) explains how to build additional software on the build system, for use on the target system.

systemd isn’t a package manager, [it’s a system and service manager](https://systemd.io/). It doesn’t manage the installed software on a system, but rather the runtime state of a system (including dependencies between services).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but, for example, yocto guide reports at https://docs.yoctoproject.org/what-i-wish-id-known.html to use Git and not the tarballs (suggest it actually). Now, if git is not installed on the distro, how should i install it?

Comment: You should install Git on the system you’re developing on, not the system running CCLinux.

Comment: Ja, but git also usefull on the device to pull when an update is available

Comment: That’s not how Yocto works. In the link you give, getting updates refers to getting Yocto updates, which is useful only on the system used to build the images. Updates on target devices aren’t done using Git.

Comment: Ok got it. i'll dig a bit more by mysel